# Update SQLite schema iOS

Tags: ios, mysql, database, sqlite

I have an app for iPad with SQLite database. The app have a button for Update the data from a web service. When I push Update button, I check the last version of Database and the version of the database of the Documents folder.
I use PRAGMA user_version for save the version of database but, I need to update the schema when database version is different of the last version of Database. The last version of database I identify with a constant in the code.
I understand, the best way is with an Alter table, but, how can I update the schema of the database regardless of how old is the version? Cause If version od database is 2 and the new version is 5, I need to update tables that might please no need to update if the version of database is 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of your app already had functions for upgrading from version 2 to 3, and to 4. Just keep them, and when needed, call them before upgrading to 5.